# How to get YouTube Video ID from PlaylistID?

Tags: java, android, youtube, youtube-api, playlist

how do I get ID of a youtube video that is part of a playlist
example a link like this:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kXYiU_JCYtU&list=PL87FA01F68C540290

this is the gdata

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/PL87FA01F68C540290?v=2&alt=jsonc&max-results=50

THIS IS MY CODE

```
public class Episodi extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

ImageView mainThumb;
TextView mainTitle;
TextView mainTime;
LinearLayout videos;
ArrayList<String> links;
URL jsonURL;


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.episodi);

    new ParseVideoDataTask().execute();
    mainThumb = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mainThumb);
    mainTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mainTitle);
    mainTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mainTime);
    videos = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.videos);

}

public class ParseVideoDataTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    int count = 0;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        URL jsonURL = null;
        URLConnection jc;
        links = new ArrayList<String>();
        try {

                jsonURL = new URL("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/" +
                "PL87FA01F68C540290" +  
                "?v=2&alt=jsonc&max-results=50");


             jc = jsonURL.openConnection(); 
             InputStream is = jc.getInputStream(); 
             String jsonTxt = IOUtils.toString(is); 
             JSONObject jj = new JSONObject(jsonTxt); 
             JSONObject jdata = jj.getJSONObject("data"); 
             JSONArray aitems = jdata.getJSONArray("items"); 
             for (int i=0;i<aitems.length();i++) {
                 JSONObject item = aitems.getJSONObject(i); 
                 JSONObject video = item.getJSONObject("video"); 
                 String title = video.getString("title");
                 JSONObject player = video.getJSONObject("player");
                 String link = player.getString("default");
                 String length = video.getString("duration");
                 JSONObject thumbnail = video.getJSONObject("thumbnail"); 
                 String thumbnailUrl = thumbnail.getString("hqDefault");
                 String[] deets = new String[4];
                 deets[0] = title;
                 deets[1] = thumbnailUrl;
                 deets[2] = length;
                 links.add(link);
                 publishProgress(deets);
             }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
        return null;
    }       



    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(final String... deets) {
        count++;
        if (count == 1) {
            Picasso.with(getBaseContext()).load(deets[1]).into(mainThumb);
            mainTitle.setText(deets[0]);
            mainTime.setText(formatLength(deets[2]));
            mainThumb.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(Episodi.this,Video.class);
                    //I want to insert .putExtra here for the VIDEO ID (example. kXYiU_JCYtU)
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            });
        } else {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)Episodi.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View video = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.videothumb, null);
            ImageView thumb = (ImageView) video.findViewById(R.id.thumb);
            TextView title = (TextView) video.findViewById(R.id.title);
            TextView time = (TextView) video.findViewById(R.id.time);
            Picasso.with(getBaseContext()).load(deets[1]).into(thumb);
            title.setText(deets[0]);
            time.setText(formatLength(deets[2]));
            video.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);
            videos.addView(video);
            video.setId(count-1);
            video.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(Episodi.this,Video.class);
                    //I want to insert .putExtra here for the VIDEO ID (example. kXYiU_JCYtU)
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}

private CharSequence formatLength(String secs) {
    int secsIn = Integer.parseInt(secs);
    int hours = secsIn / 3600,
            remainder = secsIn % 3600,
            minutes = remainder / 60,
            seconds = remainder % 60;

            return ((minutes < 10 ? "0" : "") + minutes
            + ":" + (seconds< 10 ? "0" : "") + seconds );
}

public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    for (int i=0;i<videos.getChildCount();i++) {
        View v = videos.getChildAt(i);
        if (v instanceof ImageView) {
            ImageView iv = (ImageView) v;           
            ((BitmapDrawable)iv.getDrawable()).getBitmap().recycle(); 
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

As I can see here you have JSON formated string as a response.

There are many JSON APIs, you can use provided in Android. Just make `JSONObject` and get the data you are interested in.

```
JSONObject playlist = new JSONObject(response);
// list items
JSONArray items = playlist.getJSONObject("data").getJSONArray("items");
// traverse items array and get video url
for(int i=0; i<items.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject item = items.getJSONObject(i);
    // video url
    String videoURL = item.getJSONObject("video").getJSONObject("player").getString("default");
}
```

You need to wrap all this in try-catch block.

**EDIT**

As I understood you need to parse the strings you have in the list `links`.

```
for(String link : links) {
    String id = link.split("&")[0].split("v=")[1];
    // do what you need with the link
}
```

Comment: I would really just a way to extract this line kXYiU_JCYtU indicates this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kXYiU_JCYtU&list=PL87FA01F68C540290

Comment: Then just parse the string `url.split("&")[0]`

Comment: sorry but what would I do with that? :)

Comment: sorry, i didn't see you whole comment. it should be like this `url.split("&")[0].split("v=")[1]`. `url` is your youtube link.

Comment: it can work like that? String ad = links.split("&")[0].split("v=")[1]; 
gives me the following error (The method split (String) is undefined for the type ArrayList <String>)

Comment: it can work, you need to call it upon the `String` variable. If you have list of strings then traverse it and apply this on each url you have in list.

Comment: sorry but I'm still trying to learn the language :) how do I call on String variable. Thus String ad; But it shows me the same error (The method split (String) is undefined for the type ArrayList <String>)

Comment: Post me some code so I can help you. I can't explain you the Java.

Comment: I edited the question if you do not understand something please ask :) thanks

Comment: ok then I have to do this i.putExtra("Url", id.get(v.getId())); ?